# get user country,details FQL facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can i get the user country through javascript with FQL.

`FB.API("/me")` doesn't includes the country information [i think] ,so how can i get the country and user details in one query ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any parameter called country in users table. But you can get the user's location using user_location or user_hometown or locale
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

For that you need to take the permissions from user (user_location or user_hometown)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Then FB.API("/me") will return the country info also. This will return the location field as `Array ( [id] => 111227078906045 [name] => Some City, New York )`

So you will always receive the country.

**Other Way**

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
  $country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
```

Now $country has a string such as "us" for United States and "gb" for United Kingdom etc.

Comment: what will happen if user doesn't have the user_hometown ??

Comment: Off course you don't get. Then you can depend on current_locaiton

Comment: I am sorry ,but user can change the current location too ,which will break the code ... any other way to get the country string ?

Comment: why don't to store the country in database? if you rally want to have fixed one for user

Comment: How can i get the signed request ??? i am using outside facebook.not in iframe app.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the query:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=location,hometown');
      //with user_location,user_hometown access tokens
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!